# O plt.title não reconhece a string e apresenta um erro

Tags: python, matplotlib

Esse erro começou a apresentar no meu Notebook todo, após algumas tentativas de Criar uma função para plotar gráficos.

Codigo:

````
plt.figure(figsize = (14,8))
sns.boxplot(x='Q006',y = 'NU_NOTA_TOTAL',
            data = dados_sem_nota_zero,
            hue = "TP_SEXO",
            order = renda_ordenada)
plt.title('Notas por Renda / Sexo')```

Erro:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-245-9defcbffda6f> in <module>()
      4             hue = "TP_SEXO",
      5             order = renda_ordenada)
----> 6 plt.title('Notas por Renda / Sexo')

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable



Função de criar graficos que desencadeou o erro:
def cria_grafico (x,y,titulo):
  plt.figure(figsize = (10,8))
  sns.boxplot(x=x,y = y, data=dados,order=renda_ordenada)
  plt.title("titulo")
  plt.show
````

Comment: Bem vindo ao SO em Português! A pergunta está um pouco confusa. Por exemplo, é dito ¨Função de criar graficos que desencadeou o erro:¨, mas o erro indicado não é aí.

Comment: Haverá, algures, mais acima no código, algo como ```plt.title = ```?

Answer (score 0):

Sua função rodou normal aqui, eu apenas retirei o parâmetro *order*, pois testei num dataframe qualquer aqui.

Como disse que ficou a fazer várias tentativas até concluir a função, pode ser que tenha deixado solta alguma variável com o mesmo nome da função e, nisso, o programa não consegue chamar a função (palpite). Pode tentar reiniciar o kernel e rodar seu Notebook célula por célula até a chamada da função e ver se dá certo.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).